# How do you derive the Dirac Lagrangian density for spinor fields?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, dirac-equation

I know the how the [Dirac Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_%28field_theory%29#Dirac_Lagrangian) is written but I don't understand how to derive it from the general definition $L=T-V$. So I guess I would also like to know what the Kinetic and Potential energies of a Dirac field are.

Comment: T - V is not really the "general definition" of Lagrangian. It's one of the possibilities only.

Comment: Okay if not from there, where does the Dirac Lagrangian originate?

Comment: It basically originates from the fact that you want to make the Hamiltonian of your system of fermions (actually one fermion) to be Lorentz Invariant.